# Interpreting and transforming GLM output parameters with a Gamma log link

Tags: r, glm, gamma

I built a GLM model in R with a Gamma log link and where my response variable is "1 - effectiveness". I would like to report the results of my model directly in terms of "effectiveness", but I am unsure about how to interpret and transform model coefficients and report them correctly.

I modelled "1 - effectiveness" because this was a transformation requiered to use Gamma. Effectiveness ranges from negative to 1, and therefore "1 - effectiveness" has zero to positive values, and adjust well to a Gamma.

This is my R output:

```
glm(formula = one_minus_eff ~ theat + resources + governance + 1, family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
    data = dataframe)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 0.146929   1.014147   0.145   0.8861  
theat       0.017819   0.007422   2.401   0.0248 *
resources   0.028103   0.011307   2.486   0.0206 *
governance  1.042097   0.452272   2.304   0.0306 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.9350556)

    Null deviance: 46.378  on 26  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 29.711  on 23  degrees of freedom
AIC: 257.57
```

Is this interpretation expressing the results in terms of "effectiveness" correct?:

"For `resources`, the coefficient is 0.028103. This means that, all else being equal, a one-unit increase in `resources` is associated with an increase of 0.028103 in the log-transformed "1-effectiveness" (`one_minus_eff` in R) because family is Gamma with a log link.

However, because the response variable is in log units (due to the log link function), I need to take the exponent to interpret the effect on `one_minus_eff` in its original units. The exponential of 0.028103 is approximately 1.0283.

So, a one-unit increase in `resources` is associated with an approximate 2.83% increase in the original `one_minus_eff` value, assuming all other variables in the model are held constant. This effect is relative to the units and scale of the data and the assumptions of the Gamma family with a log link.

Similarly, a one-unit decrease in `resources` would result in a **2.83% decrease in "1-effectiveness"**. I could revert that sentece by changing the sign of the coefficient and claim that the same one-unit decrease in `resources` is associated to a **2.83% increase in effectiveness**."

Is the above logic correct?

Comment: this sounds like a question which might be better suited to Cross Validated. Consider asking over there. Your question might need some edits, they may have slightly different expectations for good questions

Comment: Voted to close & migrate (if two more people vote accordingly the Q. will automatically be migrated)

Comment: Can I migrate it myself? Can't find the way to do it. Might post it at Cross Validated, but that might be duplication.